How to buffer / emit a Flux based on another publisher but with empty buffers?
How can we get the behaviour of Flux.buffer(Publisher other) but with the emission of empty buffers? Flux.buffer(Publisher) will just drop empty buffers.
Use case
Buffer a Flux and release a snapshot collection based on a triggerFlux.
The subsequent operation shall also run when there are no events.
Example
Flux<Integer> snapshotTriggerFlux = ...;
Flux<SomeEvent> eventFlux = ...;

Flux.zip(
    eventFlux.buffer(snapshotTriggerFlux), //my snapshot if available
    someOtherPublishers
)
 .doOnNext(someProcedure)

Problem
When eventFlux does not emit, buffer will stay empty and not emit any signals.
SomeProcedure will not run, when it should.
Alternatives
Flux.bufferWhen looks promising but uses two sources and might lose data if out of order. I find it impossible to ensure proper synchronisation.
Outlook
If there is no simple solution I might have overlooked, I might ask the Project Reactor team to implement Flux.buffer(Publisher other, Boolean emptyBuffers).
Workaround
I might just merge triggerFlux with eventFlux into one Flux and use something like bufferUntil on it. Complicates types.
Thank you
Martin
I tried Flux.buffer(Publisher) and found that it drops empty buffers. Confirmed by looking at the code.
Tried Flux.bufferWhen which seems to work fine but should (in theory) be dangerous.
